# How to get the date and time when uploading image to firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm uploading/sending an image to firebase storage and real-time database. How to get the current date and time when uploading the image ?

```
private void uploadImage() {
    if (imgUrl != null) {
        final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(imgUrl));

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imgUrl)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        final String currentdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                uploadProgress.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);
                        fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Notify upload = new Notify(imgDescription.getText().toString().trim(), uri.toString());
                                String uploadID = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                                mDatabaseRef.child(uploadID).setValue(upload);
                                Toast.makeText(StudentNotify.this, "Upload successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                imgDescription.setText("");
                            }
                        });


                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(StudentNotify.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        uploadProgress.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(StudentNotify.this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  What's wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: I want to send the current date and time together with the image url to firebase real-time database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get your question, you want to store the current timestamp as well when you store the image url and description in the Firebase realtime database.

You can use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP provided by the Firebase database server and store it in a new timestamp field in your database along with the url and description fields for each image. The Firebase servers write the current timestamp in UTC milliseconds in place of this value when performing writes. This value is a 13-digit numeric value.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue

Include the code below to write this value for each image

```
    fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
              Notify upload = new Notify(imgDescription.getText().toString().trim(), 
                                         uri.toString());
              String uploadID = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
              mDatabaseRef.child(uploadID).setValue(upload);

              mDatabaseRef.child(uploadID).child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

              Toast.makeText(StudentNotify.this, "Upload successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              imgDescription.setText("");
          }
    });
```

This will create a new field with key name "timestamp" for each image with a 13-digit number representing the UTC timestamp in milliseconds as below

```
{
    //...

    imagePushKeyId1: {
        url: "image url here",
        desc: "image description here"
        timestamp: 1549347429000
    }

    //....
}
```

While reading back from the database, you can get this value as a long integer in a variable say 'timestamp' and convert it to date and time as below

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
String dateTimePattern = "MMM dd, yyyy EEE h:mm a";
String dateText = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern).format(date);
```

It gives dateText in format below
Jan 28, 2019 Mon 3:52 PM

Use can get it in any format you like by modifying the dateTimePattern string, refer to the link below for details.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#date-and-time-patterns

Comment: thank you. It worked. How to retrieve Date and time from Timestamp?

Comment: Great, you can first convert the timestamp into a Date object and then use the SimpleDateFormat with a pattern to get the date and time in your desired format. I have edited the answer with an example pattern which give the dateText in the format Jan28, 2019 Mon 3:52 PM.

Comment: @Vishnu do not forgot to mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied to help others in this community :)